# Display Error messages on Screen(view)

Tags: android

I want to show Error(log) messages from catch block. How can I show all messages(stack) on a single Screen, so that user can get an idea ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

How about using Toast?

Sample:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(resourceIDForMessage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: ohh...i didn't know that i can do that.mm...nicee!!